# .NET memory model, multiple instances of the same program running simultaneously

Tags: .net, memory-model

How does the .NET CLR handle multiple instances of the same program running simultaneously?

I make the assumption that each instance is independent and occupies it's own unique memory-space and one instance can't affect another instance.

Is there a good resource on-line that (briefly!) explains how the CLR handle this and the implications?

Comment: What exactly are you interested about?  I think that you aim is too wide here...

Comment: @Daniel Mošmondor - I'm interested in finding out if there are any consequences in running multiple instances of the same .NET program simultaneously on the same machine. I thought it would be better to check than assume! I imagine that there aren't but I'm looking for something that explains how this is done so I can understand and be confident in the answer.

Comment: Code is loaded so it is shared, data is created so it is separated.  That's true for all processes on the machine. Unless you are using some IPC mechanism such as shared memory, memory mapped files, sockets, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple instances of the same app are no different than multiple instances of different apps, except that they happen to have loaded their code from the same file(s).

Answer (score 1):

Edit : Reading your own comments, what you're looking for is called "Application Isolation". This is done by the 'Application domain' concept. Go to the MSDN link for more info.

Depends on the process host (the "exe" itself, IIS, WAS, ...)

But what you have to look for is "Application domain". This is the common pattern of all these process hosts.

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Processes are still processes. .Net is just an execution context, that runs on the OS. Managed code (IL) is JIT compiled before execution and is essentially managed by the CLR. Ultimately it's still real code in real processes.